# Delegates For Events

Tags: vb.net

I use BackgroundWorkers occasionally to update another thread while not freezing the UI. I use this code often as it works well:

```
Private Delegate Sub DelegateUpdateStatus(ByVal statusText As String)

Private Sub UpdateStatus(ByVal statusText As String)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(Sub() LblStatus.Text = statusText)
    Else
        LblStatus.Text = statusText
    End If
End Sub
```

I understand this code but I do have trouble understanding how I can use this code or something like it for `ListViewMain.BeginUpdate`, `ListViewMain.EndUpdate` and `ListViewMain.Items.Add`.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: In your example code I understand that your `Sub` has the same signature as your `Delegate`, so you can use the `Delegate` to refer to your `Sub`, but I don't understand how that applies to your question?

Comment: `how I can use this code or something like it for ListViewMain.BeginUpdate, ListViewMain.EndUpdate and ListViewMain.Items.Add` - delete the `LblStatus.Text = statusText` after the `Sub()` and put `ListViewMain.BeginUpdate` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your delegate type is useless because you're not using it. You're using a Lambda expression to create a delegate so your `DelegateUpdateStatus` type is pointless.  Secondly, you should be recalling the same method in the `If` block and then doing the actual work only once, in the `Else` block:

```
Private Sub UpdateStatus(ByVal statusText As String)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(Sub() UpdateStatus(statusText))
    Else
        LblStatus.Text = statusText
    End If
End Sub
```

The actual work to be done on the UI thread is done only in the `Else` block, so you can do whatever you want there, including adding items to a `ListView`, e.g.

```
Private Sub AddListViewItems(items As IEnumerable(Of ListViewItem))
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(Sub() AddListViewItems(items))
    Else
        ListViewMain.BeginUpdate()

        For Each item in items
            ListViewMain.Items.Add(item)
        Next

        ListViewMain.EndUpdate()
    End If
End Sub
```